# Enumerate all pixel formats with AGL - how? (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, opengl, opentk, pixelformat

I would like to create a list of all available pixel formats for OpenGL. On Windows, I can do this by calling DescribePixelFormat in a loop, increasing the pixel format id, until it returns false.

Unfortunately, it seems that aglDescribePixelFormat does not work like this. Its AGLPixelFormat parameter is a pointer to an opaque struct - I can't call this in a loop.

Apple's documentation doesn't provide any hints either, nor does google. Any AGL experts out there willing to share their knowledge?

Edit: I've seen mention of a aglListPixelFmts() function but this is not listed in agl.h, nor can I find any mention in Apple's documentation. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Apple's documentation does give a hint.  Under `aglDescribePixelFormat`, it says:

> To retrieve the data in pixel format
>   objects other than the first one in
>   the list, call aglNextPixelFormat.
>   Then pass the returned pixel format
>   object to aglDescribePixelFormat to
>   retrieve an attribute value.

Comment: Thanks. This actually refers to something slightly different: on Mac OS X, you can have multiple renderers for a single pixel format. Given a pixel format, aglNextPixelFormat allows you to iterate through all compatible renderers.